# Программирование на С# ошибка в PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, button, ui

Помогите найти ошибку очень надо вроде сделал все правильно.Надо сделать так, чтобы при столкновении игрока с тегом "finish" Interactable уровня 2 был нажат, это я сделал но не понимаю как сделать сохранение, потом посидел, подумал и понял как делать, но после написания скрипта ничего не сработало
Вообщем вот код игрока который и открывает 2 уровень

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "finish") {
        LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel = 2;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(Level);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("UnlockedLevelsCount", LevelManager.countUnlockedLevel = 2);
```

Код Level Manager который и открывает с самого начала первый уровень и убирает у остальных Ineractable

```
public static int countUnlockedLevel = 1;


void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        if (i < countUnlockedLevel)
        {
            #region FirstStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = true;
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region SndStateBtn
            transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
            #endregion
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Вы привели два абсолютно одинаковых куска кода. Зачем?

Comment: Блин я случайно не то опять скопировал(

Comment: Можете исправить вопрос, нажав "править".

Comment: исправил но наверное уже никто не ответит

Comment: Метод `Start()` выполняет единожды, при создании объекта. В Вашем случае лучше код активации/деактивации вынести в ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ метод. И этот метод вызывать в `Start()` и после изменения `countUnlockedLevel`.

Comment: Можно пример? просто не знаю как вызвать в Start()

Comment: Я сделал но код не работает также при отключении игры не сохраняется уровни опять